# My Homepage Footer is Cut-off

Tags: css, weebly

I'm having issues with my website's footer ([theniftynerd.com](http://www.theniftynerd.com)). I installed a new Weebly theme a couple days. When I installed, everything was fine and looked good. All of a sudden yesterday, my homepage footer appeared broken. It does not span the full 100% width of the screen -it's like it's stuck at the width of the main body. The footer is completely fine on every other page though. 
The only edits I made to the new theme were to widen the sidebar of my blog pages using this code:

```
blog-sidebar { width: 250px; } .column-blog { float: left; width: 235px; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I also changed the background color of the theme's buttons -literally only changed the hex color value (the site was fine after both of these edits). I don't understand how the homepage footer broke and why the other pages are fine.

Here's what the footer code looks like in the CSS (I only have access to editing the CSS):

```
/* Footer */
  .footer-wrap .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .footer-wrap .wsite-footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .footer-wrap td.wsite-multicol-col {
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .footer-wrap td.wsite-multicol-col:last-child {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

I'm not the most code savvy, so any assistance is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You may make use of some tools like `http://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/` to check this. :D

Comment: @Panther I enter all the code I have access to within Weebly and it says all my items are closed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there is some unclosed tag in `<div class="container">` and because of it the footer gets into this `<div class="container">` while it mustn't. So, find a tag inside  `<div class="container">`(the one in `<div class="main-wrap">`) that has no it's closing pair and the issue will be solved)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but I'm not seeing it. I didn't edit this, so why would it be broken? And why only on the homepage?

Comment: I can access the div tags under my 5 heading types:
For example, here's one of them
Landing:
  `<div class="main-wrap">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="content-wrap">{content}</div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
   </div>

    <div class="footer-wrap">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
     </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end footer-wrap -->
 </div>`

Comment: The answer in the {content} part - I guess you edit this part with some online editor, don't you? So, open the content of this page and try to find the missing closing tag. Actually, I can't say why this happened, but, I guess, that it could be cache that persisted the page in a normal state after previous changes and after a while it revealed. First of all, save the content of the page somewhere, then, delete it from the site and check if the things get to the proper state - if so, you can be sure, that it is the content to blame for footer disappearance.